# Socket creating multiple connection on page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I’m having issues with my web server when I host my socket based web app on the cloud. But it works perfectly in my local machine, The problem is that when I refresh my page It creates another connection even though Is still one connection but in my local machine nothing like that happens. I’d appreciate any help that I can get.

When I refresh the browser I expected the browser to return the number of connected clients but it keeps increasing the number of connected clients when I refresh

Comment: Do you mean WebSockets?

Comment: Yes, websocket, I'm using the library "socket.io"